# 出した輪郭線を円や四角で囲みたい

Tags: c++, opencv

opencv C++
 輪郭線までは出せているのですが、その輪郭線を円や四角で囲む方法がわかりません

```
    #include"stdafx.h"
    #include<vector>
    #include<strstream>

    void run()
    {
        cv::Mat image;

        //メインループ


        while (1) {
       //グレースケール入力
        cv::Mat src = cv::imread("/*任意の２値画像*/", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

       // モルフォロジー処理
                cv::Mat opening;
                cv::Mat kernel(3, 3, CV_8U, cv::Scalar(1));
                cv::morphologyEx(thresh, opening, cv::MORPH_OPEN, kernel, cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
                //cv::imshow("モルフォロジー処理化", opening);

                // 背景領域抽出
                cv::Mat sure_bg;
                cv::dilate(opening, sure_bg, kernel, cv::Point(-1, -1), 3);

                // 前景領域抽出
                cv::Mat dist_transform;
                cv::distanceTransform(opening, dist_transform, CV_DIST_L2, 5);  //輪郭から距離が離れるほど濃くする
                cv::Mat sure_fg;
                double minVal, maxVal;
                cv::Point minLoc, maxLoc;
                cv::minMaxLoc(dist_transform, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
                cv::threshold(dist_transform, sure_fg, 0.2*maxVal, 255, 0);
                dist_transform = dist_transform / maxVal;

                // 不明領域抽出
                cv::Mat unknown, sure_fg_uc1;
                sure_fg.convertTo(sure_fg_uc1, CV_8UC1);
                cv::subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg_uc1, unknown);

                // 前景ラベリング
                using namespace std;

                int compCount = 0;
                vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
                vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
                sure_fg.convertTo(sure_fg, CV_32SC1, 1.0);
                cv::findContours(sure_fg, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_CCOMP, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
                if (contours.empty()) return;
                cv::Mat markers = cv::Mat::zeros(sure_fg.rows, sure_fg.cols, CV_32SC1);
                int idx = 0;
                for (; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0], compCount++)
                    cv::drawContours(markers, contours, idx, cv::Scalar::all(compCount + 1), -1, 8, hierarchy, INT_MAX);
                markers = markers + 1;

                // 不明領域は今のところゼロ
                for (int i = 0; i<markers.rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j<markers.cols; j++) {
                        unsigned char &v = unknown.at<unsigned char>(i, j);
                        if (v == 255) {
                            markers.at<int>(i, j) = 0;
                        }

                    }

                }
                watershed(hsv, markers);
                cv::Mat wshed(markers.size(), CV_8UC3);
                vector<cv::Vec3b> colorTab;
                for (int i = 0; i < compCount; i++)
                {
                    int b = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
                    int g = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
                    int r = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
                    colorTab.push_back(cv::Vec3b((uchar)b, (uchar)g, (uchar)r));
                }

                // paint the watershed image
                for (int i = 0; i < markers.rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < markers.cols; j++)
                    {
                        int index = markers.at<int>(i, j);
                        if (index == -1)
                            wshed.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 255);
                        else if (index <= 0 || index > compCount)
                            wshed.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = cv::Vec3b(0, 0, 0);
                        else
                            wshed.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) = colorTab[index - 1];
                    }
                }
                cv::Mat imgG;
                cvtColor(gray, imgG, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
                wshed = wshed * 0.5 + imgG * 0.5;
                              }
        }
```

Comment: あおき さん、一度編集をロールバックさせて頂きました。今までのご質問もあわせて、なるべく後から来た方でもご質問の流れが分かるような範囲での編集にして頂ければ幸いです。スタック・オーバーフローでは質問者さんご本人の疑問を解決することだけでなく、その後同じ疑問を持った方を助けることも目的としています。内容を残しておくことで後々別視点で有用な回答が寄せられることもあります。回答者の貢献を無駄にしないためにも、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします<(\_ \_)>

Answer (score 1):

[`boundingRect`関数](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-boundingrect) で外接矩形を、[`minEnclosingCircle`関数](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-minenclosingcircle) で外接円を計算できます。

OpenCVチュートリアルの [Creating Bounding boxes and circles for contours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) もご参考にどうぞ。

Comment: できました！１つ加えて質問なのですが書いていただいたCreating Bounding boxes and circles for contoursで四角を書きました。その四角の座標を出す何か良い方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: 参照先コードの `rectangle(drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), ...)`がそのまま矩形左上座標と矩形右下座標です。

Comment: 基本的な質問かもしれませんがcout << " x " <<br()  << \n;としたのですがコンパイルできないです。その前に何か宣言などしないといけないのでしょうか？

Comment: 値を標準出力して確認したい場合、`cout << rect.br().x` のように記述する必要があります。とりあえずは http://pynote.hatenablog.com/entry/opencv_cvrect http://pynote.hatenablog.com/entry/opencv_cvpoint 等を参考にどうぞ。

Comment: かなりやってみたのですが、座標に関してはどうしてもうまくいきません。申し訳ないのですがもう少し何かヒントになるような事を教えて頂けないでしょうか？？テンプレートマッチングという方法で書いた四角を検出する必要はあるのでしょうか？それとも、すでにtl brで左上の座標、右上の座標を出してあるからその必要はないんでしょうか？ただ、書いてもらった通りにcout<<Rect.br().xのように書いてもRectが定義されていないなど出てきてしまいます。

Comment: これ以上、こちらのコメント欄でやり取りするのは難しいと思います。一度落ち着いて、問題点をご自身の中で整理してから、別質問を起こされてはいかがですか？